# Mhchem not enabled for mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

It seems that the chemistry MathJax extension isn't enabled on mobile.

Code on main:

```
        MathJax.Hub.Config({"HTML-CSS": { preferredFont: "TeX", availableFonts: ["STIX","TeX"], linebreaks: { automatic:true }, EqnChunk: (MathJax.Hub.Browser.isMobile ? 10 : 50) },
                            tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ["$", "$"], ["\\\\(","\\\\)"] ], displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"], ["\\[", "\\]"] ], processEscapes: true, ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore|dno" },
                            TeX: { extensions: ["mhchem.js"], noUndefined: { attributes: { mathcolor: "red", mathbackground: "#FFEEEE", mathsize: "90%" } } },
                            messageStyle: "none"
        });
```

Code on mobile:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({"HTML-CSS": { preferredFont: "TeX", availableFonts: ["STIX","TeX"] },
                 tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ["$", "$"], ["\\\\(","\\\\)"] ], displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"], ["\\[", "\\]"] ], processEscapes: true, ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore|dno" },
                 TeX: { noUndefined: { attributes: { mathcolor: "red", mathbackground: "#FFEEEE", mathsize: "90%" } } },
                 messageStyle: "none"
});
```

Note the lack of the `mhchem.js` line.

Could this be fixed? It makes posts look ugly:

[image]

Comment: Same sympton reported here http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/mhchem-broken-on-mobile Maybe it is caused by the same reason?

Answer (score 5):

Mhchem is now enabled on mobile.